# Dealing with slash characters in request parameter using Express route

Tags: node.js, express

I'm currently working on a URL shortener app using Express.
I want the user to be able to enter a URL like this:

```
https://www.exampleurlshortener.com/new/https://www.google.com
```

The problem is whenever I try to specify the parameter using Express it will only extract the 'https:' section and everything after that is lost because the 2 backslashes are registering as a new route:

```
app.get('/new/:url', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.url) // outputs 'https:'
```

I thought about specifying each section as a new parameter but if `inner` is blank this ends up throwing a 404. I would need to check if inner is blank using this method otherwise the user would be able to type `https:/something/www.google.com`

```
app.get('/new/:prot/:inner/:address', (req, res) => {
  // throws 404 on valid addresses
```

Is there a simple way to solve this that I'm missing? Is the full URL available to be checked somewhere in the request? Or can parameters ignore backslashes?

Comment: Try using `req.url`, or passing the parameter through query-string (I would recommend this 2nd approach, it will also be simpler for clients of your API)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [an expression](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-paths) to for your URL placeholders:

```
app.get('/new/:url(*)', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.url) // will output 'https://www.google.com'
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. I looked through that documentation but I couldn't see an example like what you provided. Thanks.

Comment: Just a note, when I tried your code with the parameters `(.*)` I was getting 404 errors again, but using `(*)` instead worked in my case.

Comment: "The hyphen (-) and the dot (.) are interpreted literally by string-based paths.". So `(*)` is probably what you intended to do.

Comment: I was having similar issues and this thread just solved it. Thanks.

Comment: what happens if you do something like `'/new/:url(*)/:var'`

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira you can test patterns as you need on this webpage: https://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

> If any parameter contains "/", then add "(*)" after the parameter name.

**EXAMPLE**

> Route: "/change/job-entry/:order_number"
>
> The parameter "order_number" represents a value like "Anik-13/3/2023-Paharika-Srilanka"

**CHANGES**

> Route: "/change/job-entry/:order_number(*)"