# Javascript get request escape "/"

Tags: javascript, axios

My Id's in my name database look like this "Users/123"

My api has an endpoint to load data like this "api/user/Id"

But because of my the way the Id's are created with the slash, I'm getting 404 trying to hit "api/user/Users/123"

Anyway I can get Javascript / axois to play nice here?

Comment: Share your code and we can help you with this

Comment: [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: Why not remove the prefixed `Users/` from the ID when using it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this issue [Dealing with slash characters in request parameter using Express route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351738/dealing-with-slash-characters-in-request-parameter-using-express-route).

Another thing you could do is split the request. So you would have "api/user/:type/:id" and in your api concatenate the params with a slash.

Let me know if this helps!